# Ошибка UserWarning: Data Validation extension is not supported and will be removed warn(msg)

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

Выводит ошибку при обработке кода. Использую pandas + openpyxl. Файл с макросами, подгрузить к сожалению не смогу.

```
while position == 192:
    if type(excel_data.iat[position, 0]) == str:
        numberInMS.append(excel_data.iat[position, 0])
        print(
            f'позиция: {position} - значение: {excel_data.iat[position, 0]} - наименование: {excel_data.iat[position, 1]}')

    position += 1
```

Вывод: UserWarning: Data Validation extension is not supported and will be removed
warn(msg)